# Connect to specific shiny session (to implement cross-browser login)

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny application. Users can work through it partially, close the tab, and come back later, and the state is preserved. However, this does not work when the user switches browsers of course.

My end goal is to be able to log in to the shiny app via LTI (which is a standard to connect various learning tools and platforms together). My current plan is to make a little external server (or add something to shiny-server) that handles the LTI connection, and then redirects the browser to the shiny app with the correct session ID.

I would like to know:

- How is the session saved in the browser - it seems cookies are not used. Is is just sending the session ID in the HTML and the browser caches it? I know that it restores progress via a request to `http://example.com/myshinyapp/session/<session_id>/dataobj/restore_state`.
- Is there a way to make shiny load a specific session? I think one could abuse the bookmarks system, but maybe there is a more direct HTTP endpoint or R API I am missing.

Comment: I think you can use bookmarking for that
https://rstudio.github.io/shiny/reference/enableBookmarking.html, https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/share/advanced-bookmarking/

Comment: jdm, these are interesting questions. Unfortunately, iiuc, shiny serving (whether with `shiny-server`, shinyapps.io, or with the commercial Posit Connect) will at times "stop" a process and therefore the R environments enclosed within those sessions; this is typically done after a time period of inactivity (due to no user actions or no longer any connected users). Once that process is closed, there is no reconnecting to it. As such, even if you could find a way to reconnect to that session, it's a fragile endeavor since the session might not be alive still.

Answer (score 2):

Up front, I think the notion of "connecting to a specific shiny session" is fragile, since the shiny server (whether `shiny-server`, shinyapps.io, or the commercial Posit Connect) can and does cull processes due to configurable levels of inactivity. It is not safe to assume that once a process has no connected users that it sits around idle but still alive for a long period of time.

As an alternative, I suggest a mechanism for periodically saving state to some persistent store, including on-disk or in SQL (DBMS) or NoSQL (e.g., Redis). The code below is similar to bookmarks but does not require URL-munging or cookies, so therefore works across different browsers (and therefore different devices).

Notes:

- **WARNING**: the use of a "username" as the sole key for saving states is predicated on finding either `session$user` (when deployed to a server) or the `"USER"` envvar; if neither of those are found, this demonstration defaults to allowing the user to set their own username. This is clearly a security risk, please do not use user-editable usernames in production.
- I show the user their username here in a `textInput`, this will likely not be necessary or desired.
- This app is spartan, obviously some UX improvements can be made. The logic of (en|dis)abling buttons for state management is okay, it might need shoring up.
- On a similar note, I'm using `shinyjs` for the convenience of disabling buttons/inputs for this demonstration. It is not required, though I think some form of "disabling buttons" and/or interface management is justified.
- While I try to be robust to connection problems, failures, etc, I make no promise as to the resilience/robustness of this to malevolent actors or errant problems.
- I assume that the set of inputs saved as a "state" have an unlimited lifetime. You may want to consider a max-age, in which case your accessors may need to take into account age (e.g., add a timestamp when inserted into the object stored, and validate that when retrieving states).
- Similarly, you may want to considering versioning of state so that when the real app is updated, you can either adapt or nullify previous state schemas. I don't make a lot of effort here to work with invalid/incomplete saved states; have fun with that if you prefer.

I'll demonstrate using a Redis instance (`redux::hiredis()`), and specifically Redis' [hashes](https://redis.io/commands/?group=hash). I'll assume you have one available or can easily set one up (they are relatively easy to set up and available in many server environments). If you don't have Redis, I think the accessors below can easily be adapted for something else, for instance `cachem::cache_disk`.

First, the accessors since I'm using:

```r
redis <- redux::hiredis()
topic_prefix <- "saved_states/"
getstates <- function(user, prefix = topic_prefix) {
  stopifnot(
    "'user' must be length-1 character" =
      nzchar(user) && length(user) == 1,
    "'prefix' must be length-1 character" =
      nzchar(prefix) && length(prefix) == 1
  )
  tryCatch(
    unlist(redis$HKEYS(paste0(prefix, user))),
    error = function(e) {
      warning("error getting state: ", conditionMessage(e), call. = FALSE)
      list()
    })
}
getstate <- function(user, key, prefix = topic_prefix) {
  stopifnot(
    "'user' must be length-1 character" =
      nzchar(user) && length(user) == 1,
    "'key' must be length-1 character" =
      nzchar(key) && length(key) == 1,
    "'prefix' must be length-1 character" =
      nzchar(prefix) && length(prefix) == 1
  )
  json <- tryCatch(
    redis$HGET(paste0(prefix, user), key),
    error = function(e) {
      warning("error getting user state: ", conditionMessage(e), call. = FALSE)
      "{}"
    })
  tryCatch(
    jsonlite::fromJSON(json),
    error = function(e) {
      warning("error converting state: ", conditionMessage(e), call. = FALSE)
      list()
    })
}
setstate <- function(user, key, val, prefix = topic_prefix) {
  stopifnot(
    "'user' must be length-1 character" =
      nzchar(user) && length(user) == 1,
    "'key' must be length-1 character" =
      nzchar(key) && length(key) == 1,
    "'prefix' must be length-1 character" =
      nzchar(prefix) && length(prefix) == 1
  ) 
  json <- jsonlite::toJSON(val)
  tryCatch({
    redis$HSET(paste0(prefix, user), key, json)
    TRUE
  }, error = function(e) {
    warning("error saving state: ", conditionMessage(e), call. = FALSE)
    FALSE
  })
}
```

Now, the rest of the shiny app:

```r
library(shiny)
defstate <- c("Previous saved states" = "")
defvals <- list(txt = "Something", num = 42)
ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  # shinyjs::disabled(
    textInput("user", "Username (insecure)", value = ""),
  # ),
  selectizeInput("state", "States", choices = defstate, selected = ""),
  shinyjs::disabled(actionButton("getstate", "Get states")),
  shinyjs::disabled(actionButton("savestate", "Save this state")),
  shinyjs::disabled(actionButton("delstate", "Delete this state")),
  hr(),
  textInput("txt", "Some text", value = defvals$txt),
  numericInput("num", "A number", value = defvals$num)
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  keys <- reactiveValues()
  observe({
    if (!is.null(session$user)) {
      updateTextInput(session, "user", label = "Username (pulled from 'session')",
                      value = session$user)
    } else if (nzchar(user <- Sys.getenv("USER"))) {
      updateTextInput(session, "user", label = "Username (pulled from 'USER' envvar)",
                      value = user)
    } else {
      # this section should likely not exist ...
      warning("RUNNING IN INSECURE MODE, user can change their own username", call. = FALSE)
      updateTextInput(session, "user", label = "Username (INSECURE!)")
      shinyjs::enable(id = "user")
    }
  })
  observeEvent(input$user, {
    fun <- if (isTRUE(nzchar(input$user))) shinyjs::enable else shinyjs::disable
    for (id in c("getstate", "savestate", "delstate")) fun(id)
  })
  observeEvent(list(input$user, input$getstate), {
    req(nzchar(input$user))
    keys[[input$user]] <- (newkeys <- getstates(input$user))
    updateSelectizeInput(
      session, "state",
      choices = c(defstate, setNames(nm = keys[[input$user]])),
      selected = input$state)
  })
  observeEvent(input$state, {
    req(input$state)
    newstate <- getstate(input$user, input$state)
    updateTextInput(session, "txt", value = if (!is.null(newstate$txt)) newstate$txt else defvals$txt)
    updateNumericInput(session, "num", value = if (!is.null(newstate$num)) newstate$num else defvals$num)
  })
  observeEvent(input$delstate, {
    req(length(keys[[input$user]]), nzchar(input$state))
    redis$HDEL(paste0(topic_prefix, input$user), input$state)
    keys[[input$user]] <- setdiff(keys[[input$user]], input$state)
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "state", choices = c(defstate, setNames(nm = keys[[input$user]])), selected = "")
  })
  observeEvent(input$savestate, {
    now <- format(Sys.time(), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    res <- setstate(input$user, now, list(txt = input$txt, num = input$num))
    if (isTRUE(res)) {
      keys[[input$user]] <- unique(c(keys[[input$user]], now))
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "state", choices = c(defstate, setNames(nm = keys[[input$user]])), selected = now)
    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

For instance, if we start up and click the "save state" once, we see something like this:

[image: one browser (firefox)]

If we open the same URL in a different browser (chrome here), update the values, and save as a new state, we'll see:

[image: another browser (chrome), same time]

Back in the first browser, immediately clicking "get states" and selecting the most recent allows us to "import" the other browser's inputs.

[image: first browser with second browser's inputs]